# SharePoint patching issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

We applied December SharePoint patches (KB5002531 and KB5002532) on Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM) web server holding SharePoint Server 2019. After patching we are seeing following error 'The control type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' is not allowed on this page' when tried using MIM portal functionalities.
We restarted the web server and also restarted the SharePoint and IIS services. I can confirm the issue is due to patching since we have another MIM SharePoint web server which is yet to be patched and that is working fine. Does anyone know the fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article to see if it is helpful:

[The control type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' is not allowed on this page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1372987/the-control-type-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmlan?page=1)